# If python reads from top to bottom, left-to-right why we putting if end of the code?

Tags: python

Ok here is my code.
After years and years I turn back to coding. idk why?
My problem with python..

```
# Just code...

print("Hello!")


def main():
    print("Hi!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Expected:

```
Hi!
```

What happened:

```
Hello!
Hi!
```

Comment: Why were you expecting just "Hi"? Or in other words, why weren't you expecting `print("Hello!")` to run? You can [edit] to clarify if needed. BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? [What does `if __name__ == "__main__":` do?](/q/419163/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

This is so as to allow using a Python code file as a module (`import script` in some other code file) *and* as a script to be executed directly (`python script.py`).

In the former case, only the `print("Hello!")` will be executed - the `main` function will be only defined but not executed, because the `if` condition will evaluate to `False`.

In the latter case, the condition will evaluate to `True`, and in addition to the `print("Hello!")` the function `main()` will also be called, thus you get the second print as well.